# MVC5 Getting UserID from the user that's logged on to a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I previously coded a MVC4 application and now I'm upgrading it to MVC5.
I don't know what method I can use to assign the id of the user that's currently logged on to my application to UserID, I need it assigned so that I can save the information when the User creates a "Ticket"

In MVC4 I used `UserID = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId`

```
   public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TicketID,Issue,IssuedTo,Author,Priority,CategoryID,UserID")] TicketVM model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ConfigureViewModel(model);
            return View(model);
        }
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket
        {
            UserID = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, <-- ERROR
            Issue = model.Issue,
            IssuedTo = model.IssuedTo,
            CategoryID = model.CategoryID,
            Priority = model.Priority
        };
        db.Tickets.Add(ticket);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use

```
ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

To get the current ApplicationUser, when i need the ID i usually need the user too so..

Edit : I would try to do ->

```
Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

ticket.UserId = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId());
ticket.OtherVariables = ...;
```

The answer is the above code but i'm pretty sure it would of worked even with your code by replacing (int) into Convert.ToInt32(...) or Int32.TryParse(...)

you can't use (int) with a string.

Comment: But I need user to be inside `        Ticket ticket = new Ticket {...}` Anything I put it becomes an error.

Comment: @JasonWan Try what i edited on my post, that's what i would try

Comment: I need them inside so I can add properties to the model.

Comment: @JasonWan Have you Tried Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

and adding the properties using ticket.UserId = ....?

Comment: @what's code for userID? I tried `ticket.UserID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());` says `The type arguments for method 'UserManagerExtensions.FindById<TUser, TKey>(UserManager<TUser, TKey>, TKey)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @JasonWan you just need to do ticket.userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

By giving the code you just sent you are giving an Applicationuser to something expecting a userId

Comment: UserID is an int in my TicketVM (ViewModel) `ticket.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();` Returns a string and passes it to UserID which doesn't work because you can't pass a string to an int. I've tried to cast it to an int but it doesn't work.

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId());

Comment: Thanks! It's work. Can you edit your solution in the comment.

Comment: @JasonWan Answer is now there, Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use on Controller: **User.Identity.GetUserId()**

Comment: `UserID = model.Identity.GetUserId()`'TicketVM' does not contain a definition for 'Identity' and no extension method 'Identity' accepting a first argument of type 'TicketVM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `UserID = model.UserID.Identity.GetUserId()`  'int' does not contain a definition for 'Identity' and no extension method 'Identity' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @JasonWan - `User.Identity.GetUserId()`, not `model.Identity.GetUserId()`. `User` should be a property accessible from within your controller.

Comment: User.Identity.GetUserId() returns a string and UserID is an int. I can't cast it to an int as well.